# convert separate 1D np.arrays into a list of 2D np.arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas, array-broadcasting

I'm trying to convert three 1D arrays into a list of 2D arrays. I've managed to do this by creating an empty ndarray and populating it line by line. Could someone show me a more elegant approach?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
one=np.arange(1,4,1)
two=np.arange(10,40,10)
three=np.arange(100,400,100)
df=pd.DataFrame({'col1':one,'col2':two,'col3':three})

desired_output=[np.array([[1.,10.],[1.,100.]]),np.array([[2.,20.],[2.,200.]]),np.array([[3.,30.],[3.,300.]])]
```

current, inelegant approach that works:

```
output=[]
for i in range(len(df)):
    temp=np.zeros(shape=(2,2))
    temp[0][0]=df.iloc[i,0]
    temp[0][1]=df.iloc[i,1]
    temp[1][0]=df.iloc[i,0]
    temp[1][1]=df.iloc[i,2]
    output.append(temp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach using [`np.column_stack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html) and [`np.vsplit`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.vsplit.html) -

```
arr2D = np.column_stack((df['col1'],df['col2'],df['col1'],df['col3']))
out_list = np.vsplit(arr2D.reshape(-1,2),arr2D.shape[0])
```

Basically, we use `np.column_stack` to stack `column-1` with `column-2` and then again `column-1` with `column-3` to give us a 2D NumPy array `arr2D` of shape `N x 4`. Next, we reshape `arr2D` to a `2*N X 2` array and split along the rows with `np.vsplit` to give us the expected list of `2D` arrays.

Sample run -

```
>>> df
   col1  col2  col3
0     1    10   100
1     2    20   200
2     3    30   300
3     4    40   400
4     5    50   500
5     6    60   600
>>> arr2D = np.column_stack((df['col1'],df['col2'],df['col1'],df['col3']))
>>> out_list = np.vsplit(arr2D.reshape(-1,2),arr2D.shape[0])
>>> print out_list
[array([[  1,  10],
       [  1, 100]]), array([[  2,  20],
       [  2, 200]]), array([[  3,  30],
       [  3, 300]]), array([[  4,  40],
       [  4, 400]]), array([[  5,  50],
       [  5, 500]]), array([[  6,  60],
       [  6, 600]])]
```

Answer (score 2):

so first of all you can get array from `df` values by simply doing the following

```
In [61]:
arr = df.values
arr
Out[61]:
array([[  1,  10, 100],
       [  2,  20, 200],
       [  3,  30, 300]])
```

then add the first column in the array again

```
In [73]:
arr_mod = np.hstack((arr , arr[: , 0][:, np.newaxis]))
arr_mod
Out[73]:
array([[  1,  10, 100,   1],
       [  2,  20, 200,   2],
       [  3,  30, 300,   3]])
```

swap the column you've just added with the last column in the array

```
In [74]:
arr_mod[: , [2 , 3]] = arr_mod [:  , [3 , 2]]
arr_mod
Out[74]:
array([[  1,  10,   1, 100],
       [  2,  20,   2, 200],
       [  3,  30,   3, 300]])
```

then convert this 2d `array` to 3d `array` and convert it to list

```
In [78]:
list(arr_mod.reshape( -1, 2 , 2))
Out[78]:
[array([[  1,  10],
        [  1, 100]]), array([[  2,  20],
        [  2, 200]]), array([[  3,  30],
        [  3, 300]])]
```